# How to call functions within a XTemplate extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs

Here is my view

```
Ext.define('ValidationErrorView', {
    extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.validationErrorView',
    layout : 'fit',
    overflow : 'auto',
    autoScroll : true,
    xTitle : 'Title',
    XFun :function(name){
        return "Hello " + name;
    }

    border : false,

    initComponent : function() {
        var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div>{xTitle}',
            '<p>{[xFun(name)]}',
            '</div>',
            '</tpl>'
        );
    }   
});
```

There are xTitle and xFun() that I want to use in my template. I am using {[..]} to call my function but this is not working? How can I use both xTitle and XFun() in the template ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the function in below format:

```
initComponent : function() {
    var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div>{xTitle}',
        '<p>{[this.xFun(name)]}',
        '</div>',
        '</tpl>',
        {
            XFun :function(name){
               return "Hello " + name;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

This will work for sure.I have removed your function Xfun which is outside of initComponent().

Comment: yes this works. But I am not able to access XTitle inside this

Comment: You need to pass **values** as a parameter to xFun(), this value is current record of store.If you put breakpoint inside this xFun  you will see xTitle in that record.Please check this and reply.

Comment: but how can I access XTitle (outside initXomponent )in xFun () (inside initComponent)

Comment: You can access same variable by getting that panel's object in below way:
**Ext.getCmp(<panel Id>).xTitle**
By this you will get that variable inside xFun ().Please check this .

Comment: how to get panel id ?

Comment: assign some id to that panel like **id:'myPanel'**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133367/discussion-between-tejas1991-and-sunil-garg).

Comment: Don't use Ext.getCmp !!! Use instead of 'id', 'itemId' and instead of Ext.getCmp, this.down('#<itemIdValue>'). An id has to be unique in your displayed components, itemId must be unique within the object itself.

Comment: An Ext.XTemplate has to be applied and requires a simple key paired object. What you can do before applying it is to Ext.apply some extra values, like the panel title to the object that your are going to apply to the element that holds the XTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

```
initComponent : function() {
  var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
    '<div>{xTitle}',
    '<p>{[this.xFun(values.name)]}',
    '</div>',
    '</tpl>',
    {
      XFun :function(name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
      }
    }
  );
}
```

`this values.X`(variable name which you are referring) worked for me.
and xTitle can be acceess from XFun function like this.xTitle..